# Add a transaction generated offline to the official client

Tags: transactions, client, bitcoin-core

I have a transaction that I generated/signed using a custom tool.  I'd like to make sure it was generated correctly by submitting it to the official client and watching the logs to see if it is accepted.

What is the best way to manually submit a transaction to the official client (either json or binary)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 0.7 you will be able to send it to bitcoind through a "sendrawtransaction" [JSON API call](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list).